# How can I define or express that y has the same length as x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to write a mathematical function where:

- $x$ is the input;  a string of mixed binary digits ($0$s & $1$s), of undetermined length, and
- $y$ is a string of all binary $1$s, with the same length (amount of digits) as the input $x$.
- $z$ is the output; the result of some interaction between $x\  \&\  y$

For example:

$if\qquad\ \ \ \ \ \ \ x = 0111001001110010$
$then\ \ \ \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,y = 1111111111111111$

but

$if\qquad\ \ \ \ \ \ \ x = 01110010$
$then\ \ \ \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,y = 11111111$

and so on..

How could I express or represent this in a mathematical context, in a slick/short, symbolic and formulaic style?
Perhaps there's some kind of shorthand or common convention I can use.

Answer (score 2):

Consider both $x,y$ as binary integers, and let $\ell(x)$ denote the length of $x$, then $y = 2^{\ell(x)}-1$.

Comment: Nice. Is this transferable though? How would you do the same for all $0$s instead of all $1$s?

Comment: @tjt263 there you have to define a concatenation operation on strings, and write something like ${`0\text{'}}^{\ell(x)}$.